# Does vsftpd support Clear Command Channel (CCC)?

Tags: ftp, ftps, vsftpd

Does the VSFTPD server support Clear Command Channel (CCC) per [RFC 2228](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228)?

If it does support CCC, does it need to be enabled? Or, is it enabled with the whole FTPS suite of configuration parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that no, it does not support CCC.